JS GC in closure
hi i have a query and was unable to get exact answer. I have a below closure function
function closure() {let innerVal; return function() {innerVal = innerVal+10}}
let inst = closure();
inst();
console.log('end');

will innerVal be cleared during GC after inst() is called or not?

yes   , if nothing references something, it's GC'ed.  does not matter were it's initialised.

I would think that innerVal will not be GC'ed until inst becomes undefined?

@evolutionxbox  If nothing references inst its GC'ed, no need to mark it undefined.  eg. If you ran this in just a <script/> tag, it will get GC'ed immediately unless say you had the debugger open and held a reference to inst.

I created a little demo using WeakRef
You can run it and wait 100 seconds


let outerRef;
function closure() {
  let innerVal = { v: 0 }
  outerRef = new WeakRef(innerVal)
  return function() {
    innerVal = innerVal.v + 10
  }
}
let inst = closure();
inst();
console.log('end');

setTimeout(() => {
  const v = outerRef.deref()
  console.log(v)
}, 100000)



It prints undefined in the end so the object has been garbage collected

That answer does not answer the question. The question has been "cleared during GC after inst() is called", not "cleared during GC 100 seconds after inst() is called".

@Davi 100 seconds after inst() is still after inst()

Yes, but that does not explain why the artificial delay of 100 seconds is required. Why not inst(); console.log('end'); console.log(outerRef.deref());, since then outerRef.deref() is called after inst() as well, long before 100 seconds have passed.

@Davi  I think Konrad's snippet is a good coding way of showing what's happening.   When something is GC'ed is an implementation detail.  The 100 seconds is of course just to make sure the GC has done it's thing, but you could speed that up by clicking the "Collect Garbage" in the debugger.  The point is innerVal is not leaked, and during GC it's cleared.

@Davi   outerRef.deref() note that has nothing to do with why it's GC'ed, in case that's what was throwing you.


will innerVal be cleared during GC after inst() is called or not?

It won't be garbage collected until after the invocation. However, no garbage collection algorithm is specified in the ECMAScript language specification. So…

whether or not the memory will be freed before process termination, and
the exact timing of the action

…depends on the specific runtime implementation: you will need to consult the documentation/source code of the runtime in question to obtain that information. You can learn more about garbage collection observability at the Memory management article on MDN.

What you say is totally correct, but I think the OP is more thinking higher level.  eg.  Does innerVal become available to GC during a mark-and-sweep, and the answer is of course yes.  IOW: I believe the OP is worried that innerVal stays in memory after the function is invoked.  Fortunately is does get marked for GC, or pretty much all functional coding in JS would have serious memory issues.. :)
